# Consulta SQL 4 tablas

Tags: sql, subconsultas

Tengo estas 4 tablas, me tengo que traer los productos que tengan la categoría que le indique, sin embargo cuando algo la consulta me devuelve vacío como si ningún objeto cumpliera la condición.
Es para un controlador de modo que no se si tenga que insertar otro campo mediante un foreach a una de las tablas para que la consulta de frutos, cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Esta es la consulta que tengo:

```
SELECT productos.* 
from productos
INNER JOIN productos_tallas_aplicadas ON productos.id = productos_tallas_aplicadas.id_producto
INNER JOIN productos_tallas on productos_tallas_aplicadas.id_talla= productos_tallas.id
INNER JOIN productos_categorias on productos_categorias.id_talla= productos_tallas.id
WHERE productos_categorias.id_talla=83
```

también intente  a la inversa:

```
SELECT productos.* 
from productos_categorias
INNER JOIN productos_tallas ON productos_categorias.id_talla = productos_tallas.id_padre 
INNER JOIN productos_tallas_aplicadas on productos_tallas_aplicadas.id_producto=productos_tallas.id
INNER JOIN productos on productos_tallas_aplicadas.id_producto=productos.id WHERE productos_categoria.id_talla=5
```

[image: estas son las 4 tablas]

Comment: si sacas el where, trae algo?

Comment: ¿Probaste con `LEFT JOIN` en vez de con `INNER JOIN` en todos los casos? Otro método útil para depurar es ir agregando las tablas una por una, así, cuando deje de entregar datos sabrás que el problema está en los datos de la última tabla que hayas agregado.